# How do I add a different prefix to each line?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a list of names in a list/text file (file *test.txt*).

For example:

```
smith
johnson
west
```

How would I add every letter as a prefix for each line, and output it as a new text file?

Desired output:

```
asmith
bsmith
csmith
dsmith
...
ajohnson
bjohnson
cjohnson
etc., etc.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (asc=97; asc<=122; asc++)printf ("%c%s\n", asc, $0) }' infile
```

we used printf and its `%c` (character conversion modifier, see [man awk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) for more details) to print the character converted of ASCII lower-case English letters start from ascii-code: 97 (character `a`) upto ascii-code:122 (character `z`) followed by the current line itself. [see ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 6):

Something like the following can do the trick:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r i; do
  for j in {a..z}; do
    echo "${j}${i}"
  done
done < input_file > new_text_file
# use `>> new_text_file` to append instead of overwrite
```

The `while` loop reads the names from file, the `for` loop generates letters from a to z. The `echo` command concatenates the letters from a to z and the names, read from file.

Comment: Interestingly, this is a pure shell solution that does not require any external program. Also, you can redirect the output of the outer for loop to file to more easily determine if you want `>>` or `>`. It could benefit from proper quoting though (unless it's zsh).

Comment: Also, slow if the input file is big. Because the shell is slow.

Comment: @ilkkachu, IMHO the difference is not so huge. For 50000 source words my exec for less than 45 secs, `awk` version for 13 secs :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov, ok, I got bigger differences. As in the shell being > 10x slower...

Comment: @ilkkachu, what I saw is bigger difference when deal with less source words

Answer (score 6):

Do a cross join with the `join` utility by trying to join on a non-existing column:

```bsh
join -1 2 -2 2 -o 2.1,1.1 file <( printf '%s\n' {a..z} ) | sed 's/\(.\) /\1/'
```

or, without the process substitution:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' {a..z} | join -1 2 -2 2 -o 2.1,1.1 file - | sed 's/\(.\) /\1/'
```

The `sed` at the end removes the space between the two outputted columns from `join`.

The options used with the `join` command specifies to to join on the *second* column of each file (`-1 2` and `-2 2`).  Since this column does not exist, you will get an "all-versus-all" effect.  The `-o` option and it's option-argument is for specifying the output format.  We get the second file's data before the first file's data with `-o 2.1,1.1` ("the first column from the second file, followed by the first column from the first file").

The output would be

```
asmith
bsmith
csmith
dsmith
esmith
fsmith

etc.
```

Comment: Cool!  some variants `echo -ne {a..z}"\n" | join -j 20 - file | cut -c2,4-`

Answer (score 4):

Can be applied `Brace Expansion`

```bsh
eval printf "'%s\n'" "{a..z}{$(paste -sd, file)}"
```

After executing the `eval` command, we have the following:

```
printf '%s\n' {a..z}{smith,johnson,west}
```

UPDATE:

```
eval printf "'%s\n'" "{$(paste -sd, file)}\ {a..z}" | column -to '' -O2
```

`-O2` - Capital `o`. columns order on output. Start with a second  column.

Comment: Note that this would produce `asmith`, `ajohnson`, `awest`, etc. instead of `asmith`, `bsmith` etc.

Comment: @ilkkachu. Fixed in the update section. I mixed up the order.